# HashSet not removing an item

Tags: c#, hashset

Im not sure what the problem here is,

i got a `HashSet<object>` called _itemsToProcess.

Eventually in my code (no multitrheading) i want to remove items from the hashset

```
_itemsToProcess.Remove(item);
```

This doesnt work.
I also tried

```
_itemsToProcess.RemoveWhere(i=>i.Equals(item));
```

Well it looks trivial, but i can guarantee, item is inside _itemsToProcess.
I checked in debugging via

```
_itemsToProcess.Any(item.Equals) // Returns true
_itemsToProcess.Contains(item)   // Returns false

item.GetHashcode() == _itemsToProcess.First().GetHashcode()  // returns true aswell.
```

The item doesnt implement ICompareable nor IEquatable so im out of ideas here.

Example (Simplified alot, since this is kind of a big thing)

```
readonly _itemsToProcess = new HashSet<object>();

void getItems()
{
    foreach(object o in getObjects())
         if(meetsCriteria(o)) _itemsToProcess.Add(o);

}



void processItems()
{
   if(_itemsToProcess.Count> 0)
   { 
      foreach(object item in _itemsToProcess.Where(criteria).ToArray())
          processItem(item);
   }
}

// This gets called in different ways
void processItem(object item)
{ 
     ... do stuff
     if(succes)
         _itemsToProcess.Remove(item);
}
```

**So Rephrasing the problem**

```
var compare = _itemsToProcess.First();
compare.GetHashcode() == item.GerHashcode() // true
compare.Equals(item) // true

_itemsToProcess.Contains(item)  // false, why?
```

Comment: This would happen if your `GetHashCode()` or `Equals()` methods are broken

Comment: Does it implement `IEquatable`?

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Make sure you find the item by some unique property

Comment: At this point a minimal example reproducing the bug would help :).

Comment: Is that code actually what you're writing or are you leaving out your LINQ expressions for brevity?

Comment: The items in _itemsToProcess are selected by a linq Where and then also with a ToArray() .

Comment: Does your item's class override the `Equals` or `GetHashCode` methods?

Comment: Please show the code for Equals and GetHashCode for the class of `item`

Comment: I cant, this is way too companyspecific to simplyfy here in any means. I suppose i have to focus on those methods then. Im not sure why Equals returns true then and also why Hashcodes are the same.

Comment: Hashcodes are allowed to be the same - that is called a collision. In fact, it is a good thing that collisions happen, because it is very important to the proper operation of a hash table.

Comment: See here for more information on how this stuff is supposed to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden

Comment: I guess i figured it out while driving home. When the item is added to the hashset, it has a different hashcode, since there may be some properties changing while processing the item. As this is an implementation way down in a baseclass, this probably will casue some sideeffects when fixig...

Comment: @CSharpie You are right, hash codes need to remain constant through the life of the object (or at least while it's in a `HashSet` or `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the answer is:

when the item was added to the Hashset, the GetHashcode returned a different value.
Since the processing seemed to change a propertie that was taken into account in that method, the gethashcode returned a different value at the end.

So this explains why even contains didnt work.

Thank you for your help.